# What does "realize SoP function using gates with arbitrary number of inputs" mean?

Tags: logic-gates

I am confused what "gates with arbitrary number of inputs" mean. If we are asked to realize function SoP(0,2,3,6) using standard truth table using gates with arbitrary number of inputs... how is it different from standard boolean expression( after simplification from full sum of minterms): 
$$x_1'x_3' + x_1'x_2 + x_2x_3'$$

This can be realized as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAoaHg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

BUT, problem says to realize SoP(0,2,3,6) with gates of arbitrary number of inputs...
I am not sure what to do with it.
Need help!
Thanks

Comment: A different version of the question may restrict you to 2-input gates.

Answer (score 1):

It means your AND and OR gates are allowed to have as many inputs as you need. For example, if you needed a product term with 8 inputs, that would be allowed.

If you had been asked to implement the circuit using standard 7400-series logic, for example, an 8-input gate might not be available, and you would have to make an equivalent circuit using several gates with fewer inputs per gate.

Comment: The 7400-series actually has 1, 2, 3, 4 and 8 input gates. And you can tie off unused inputs for fill in the hole. But past 8 iputs you have to chain gates together.